# gradlew is not returning error status of flyway command

Tags: gradle, flyway, gradlew

When gradlew runs flywayRepair or flywayMigrate, return status is always 0 (zero) regardless of success or failure:

```
./gradlew --quiet -Pflyway.initOnMigrate=true -Pflyway.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mars flywayRepair

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':common:flywayRepair'.
> Error occurred while executing flywayRepair
  Unable to obtain Jdbc connection from DataSource (jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mars) for user 'flyaway'
  Communications link failure

  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
  Connection refused


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Exit status from flywayRepair for mars is 0
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Are you saying that "Exit status from flywayRepair for mars is 0" is part of the output, and is that the problem? Or are you talking about the actual exit status of the `gradle` command?

Comment: "Exit status from fltwatRepair for mars is 0" is emitted by my shell script which invokes the gradle task. I'll follow-up with link to script example

Comment: Sounds like a problem with your shell script. A failed Gradle build has exit status 1.

Comment: Deploy script is posted to https://github.com/Jaff/work_examples.git where the script 'marssrv-marsdb.sh' is intended to be invoked by deployment automation when a new build might require schema migration, while the script 'db-repair' was created to manually test a different strategy by applying the flyway functions individually as opposed to collectively as they are in the deploy script.

Answer (score 5):

Both `gradle` and `gradlew` will return exit status 1 for a failed build, so this is likely a problem with your shell script. Perhaps see [Bash - how to check the exit status of pipe command](http://scratching.psybermonkey.net/2011/01/bash-how-to-check-exit-status-of-pipe.html).

Answer (score 1):

You are checking the exit status of /usr/bin/tee in your shell script, as this is the last executed command and this will of course always be 0 in your case.

You should test $PIPESTATUS[0] instead as documented on this page: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html

Comment: Just to expand on this, you could also set -o pipefail which will prevent errors in a pipeline from being masked. See http://redsymbol.net/articles/unofficial-bash-strict-mode/ for more details.

Comment: Well, my link contained this option too ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a Gradle issue. I suggest you file an issue with them.